# Install windows 7 software on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, inno-setup

I've tried to install my software built on Windows 7 on a PC having windows 8 and it failed. Unfortunately it was not an English Win8-Version so the error message told something like "Can't continue because the device is not identified".

The message came right after starting the installer (exe-file). The installer was created with InnoSetup (if it matters). I have tried to install as Administrator - same result.

I'm pretty sure, we've been able to install just for testing the same software (only earlier version) on one of the first versions of Win8 and It worked.

Is there any better means to fin out, where the installation stopped? Some kind of installation logs on Win8? Is Win8 backward-compatible at all?

P.S. if it matters:
The software is based on Qt4.8.4 and OpenCV and built with VS2008/C++

Comment: If you have sources of installer you can detect Windows version and set compatibility option automatically.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Slappy: Interesting, thanks! Yes, of cause I have the sources. I'll check the recent version of InnoSetup and this option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try using the Windows 7 compatibility mode.

1. Right click on the executable.

[image]

2. Select `properties`.

[image]

3. Switch to the `compatibility` tab.

[image]

4. Enable the compatibility mode.

[image]

5. Set the compatibility mode to Windows 7.

[image]

6. And apply settings.

[image]

*Sorry if this is an insult to your intelligence. I wanted to practice the Windows Steps recorder.*

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try it soon and come back! Screen-shots are great. In Win8 I've even managed to fail installing skype.

Comment: Just don't forget to distribute the installation manual with these pictures, because you know, customers are not always system admins ;-) Now seriously, why don't you try to analyze why this happens ? For instance, if your setup was built in Inno Setup version that is compatible with Windows 8, try to run the setup with the [`/LOG`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=LOG) parameter, if not re-build the setup in recent version of IS.

Comment: @TLama: thanks for the hint with the /LOG. I'll try. I thought, the installer exe was not executed at all.Nothing of usual initial Installer UI was displayed. For the future, I think there is no way but setting up build-machine for win8 also.

Comment: Yes, having a dedicated test machine is a must these days (MS seems to be more and more restrictive). Anyway, make sure that you use at least Inno Setup 5.5.2 for running on Windows 8, or 5.5.4 for running on Windows 8.1. These versions added the compatibility sections to the Inno Setup manifests (and I guess that not having them might cause some troubles). The best is using the most recent version (at this time 5.5.5).